# Call method by ngComponentOutlet

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm searching how to call a method of a component called dynamically by ngComponentOutlet.

Inside my Caller

```
this.dialog.open(FormDialogComponent, {data: {body: ChildComponent}});
```

FormDialogComponent

```
export interface FormDialogData {
    title: string,
    body: Type<any>
}

export class FormDialogComponent {
    @ViewChild(ChildComponent) child!: ChildComponent;
    constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<FormDialogComponent>, @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: FormDialogData) {}
    save(){
        this.child.save(); // trying to call save() method of childComponent not working
    }
}
```

How can I call call the save method of my child?

**ADD**

I forget to se the html part

```
<ng-container [ngComponentOutlet]="data.body" #child></ng-container>
```

Comment: Can you access `this.data.body`?

Comment: yes but it's the ChildComponentConstructor not the object created, the code is displaying my ChildComponent, but I can't access to it after

Comment: Try replace `@ViewChild` with `@ContentChild`. `@ViewChild` can only see the template created inside the host. `@ContentChild` can see what is passed in.

Comment: Hi @skouch2022,
sry I mist your answer, I fixed it by building the component in typescript and manipulating it by that way. It's for me more a bug fix than the way I would do it.
So I just tried your way to do it.
It display my child component but "child" is giving an undefined result
(I checked it with a click action so the load process is done when I test it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it

the caller stay the self

in My formDialogComponent.ts

```
@ViewChild('formComponent', {read: ViewContainerRef}) viewContainerRef!: ViewContainerRef;
```

also in formDialogComponent.ts

```
// Create my component
this.childComponent = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(this.data.body).instance;
```

in formDialogComponent.html

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="childComponent.save()"><mat-icon>add</mat-icon></button>
```